# Limit of quotient involving floor function and identity function

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor}{x}=1$$

L'Hôpital's rule seems to fail here, since the floor function is not differentiable for integers. What other ways are there to prove this?

Comment: Try squeezing it.

Comment: yes you can squeeze it between for example x+1 and x-1 in numerator

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
x=\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\zeta
$$
where $0\leq \zeta<1.$ Then
$$
\frac{x}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}=1+\frac{\zeta}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}\to1
$$
as $x\to \infty$ since $\zeta/\lfloor{x}\rfloor\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: You swapped nominator and denominator with respect to the question, otherwise fine.

Answer (score 0):

Big hint:  $x-1 \le \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.